# Issue of ps_files_cleanup_dir: Permission denied

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection, ini, permission-denied

With the probability of 10% , I'm getting the below issue in my project :

```
ps_files_cleanup_dir opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed permission denied (13)
```

As per my some R & D i understand the issue causes is :

> PHP is trying to delete the session files while this is also being
>   done by a cron-job put on the system by the Debian package maintainers
>   of PHP. The package maintainers of Ubuntu  believed that the solution for
>   cleaning up the session data in PHP is insecure.

So, i have search Internet around to solve this issue and found 2 solutions :

> 1. `php.ini` set `session.gc_probability` to `0`.
> 2. Write the custom path in `session.save_path`.
>
> The Problem of Solution 1 is I'm Dis-allowing PHP to Manage the
>   **Garbage Collection Process** and let the Giving all authentication to Operating System (Ubuntu 12.04) Maintainers to handle this and this
>   could be caused to insecurity in PHP. So, I'm not going with this
>   solution.
>
> And for the 2nd one I have to changes the Session Default path which
>   will use by php and the default path (May be tmp path) handled by
>   Ubntu Maintainers.

So, in both of the above two solutions which could be Best and secure ? Or Is there any other solution for such Permission issue of session for Ubuntu Os ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could (and maybe should) use your own session handler; such as a database backed one.  Then you can scale sessions beyond a single instance and solve your problem at the same time.

Edit: You can use this old code I have, which may need some modification for the DBAL.

```html
<?php

  require_once('lib/Mapper.php');

  class Session extends Mapper {
   
   protected $_pKey = 'session_id';
   protected $_table = 'sessions';
   protected $_columns = array('session_id', 'session_data', 'expires', 'updated');
   
   protected $_session_id = NULL;
   protected $_lifetime = NULL;
   
   protected $_acl = NULL;
   
   public function __construct(Database $db, $session_id = NULL){
    parent::__construct($db);
    
    $this->_session_id = $session_id;
    
    // Read the maxlifetime setting from PHP
    $this->_lifetime = ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");
   }
   
   public function __destruct(){
    session_write_close();
   }
   
   public function open($save_path, $session_id){
    return true;
   }
   
   public function read($session_id){
    $data = $this->find(array('session_id' => $session_id));
    if(!empty($data[0]))
     $session = $data[0]['session_data'];
    return (!empty($session)) ? $session : '';
   }
   
   public function write($session_id, $data){
    // where does the session data come from??? set it in the code in the auth and login!!!
    $bind = array('session_id' => $session_id, 'session_data' => $data, 'expires' => REQUEST_TIME + $this->_lifetime, 'updated' => REQUEST_TIME);
    if($this->replace($bind)){
     return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
   
   public function close(){
    return true;
   }
   
   public function destroy($session_id){
    $this->remove($session_id);
    return true;
   }
   
   public function gc(){ 
    $this->_db->query('DELETE FROM '.$this->_table.' WHERE expires < '.(REQUEST_TIME + $this->_lifetime));
    return true;
   }
   
   public function setId($id){
    $this->_session_id = $id;
   }
   
    public function getId(){
      return $this->_session_id;
    }
   
    public function find($params = array(), $order = array(), $skip = 0, $limit = NULL){
      return $this->_finder($params, $order, $skip, $limit);
    }
   
  }

$Session = new Session($_db);
// Register this object as the session handler
session_set_save_handler(
 array( $Session, "open" ),
 array( $Session, "close" ),
 array( $Session, "read" ),
 array( $Session, "write"),
 array( $Session, "destroy"),
 array( $Session, "gc" )
);
session_start();
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
```

Comment: `Own Session Handler` Means you want me to use the custom session path ?

Comment: See my updated comment and essentially, yes (but without having to modify php.ini)

Comment: Ok this could be 3rd solution but I need to make sure that the code will work perfectly for my session handlers. As Just only for 10% probability of warning , i can't use the `own or custom session`

Comment: You could add something to one of the methods, like the constructor, destructor or something that calls gc() on 10% of requests. i.e. if(rand(1,100)%10 == 0) $this->gc();

Comment: Also, you would never run into the error with a DB backed session handler as your code would never be attempting to remove file backed session files and your debian instance would be removing files from unused sessions (because they are now DB backed)

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm waiting for some more solutions and suggestions otherwise i'll try with you're one.